# hibernate is not in sync with my database

Tags: mysql, hibernate

```
  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "ServerLayerPU")
  protected EntityManager m_entityManager;

   m_entityManager.persist(entity);
   m_entityManager.flush();
```

I am trying to get my new entity object to be in sync with what has been committed to the db.  I originally put in flush which I thought solved the problem but the problem has reappeared during greater testing.  When this entity is committed to the db, triggers occur that affect another table/entity and I need this to be reflected.  How should I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

`flush()` instructs the entity manager to detect all changes done to managed entities, and send them to the database. It does not commit the transaction, nor cause data to be re-read from the database. (How would Hibernate know which data to re-read? You don't expect it to re-read everything just in case a trigger modified the data it inserted?).

You can re-read an entity with [`refresh()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: Refresh does the trick.  I am wandering what is the appropriate way of managing this kind of synchronization.  I am reluctant to litter my code with refresh statements just to guarantee my entity objects have uptodate information.

Answer (score 0):

When a database trigger changes the state of the records , these changes will not be reflected in the corresponding instances in the hibernate session .You have to use  [session.refresh()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#refresh%28java.lang.Object%29) to update these instances with the latest values from the underlying database.